# How to pass values in action.setParms

Tags: lightning-aura-components

How to pass Sobject Api and field name in Action.setparams

```
 ({
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    var opts=[];
    var action = component.get("c.getPicklistValues");
    action.setParams({

    });
```

}
})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the basics of [Calling a Server-Side Action](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_call.htm) ,go through it.

```
  action.setParams({objectAPI: 'ApiName here', fieldName : 'FieldNameHere' });
```

Comment: ya..okay..its look like hard code right..so i posted that question thanks

Comment: In the client side,Iam getting javascript value some thing like this

Comment: I cant get you clearly